# Default Time To Live (TTL) on AWS Elasticache Redis implementation

Tags: amazon-web-services, cache, redis

What is the default Time To Live (TTL) in the AWS Elasticache Redis Implementation?

I figured I could get it from the redis-cli, but looks like it doesn't support the `CONFIG GET *` syntax generally available in redis.

It's possible as well that it simply uses an LRU policy to expire, but I haven't found that stated in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

There is no default ttl for Redis. You need to explicitly set ttl with expire commands.
http://redis.io/commands/expire

> It's possible as well that it simply uses an LRU policy to expire, but I haven't found that stated in the docs.

Default setting for LRU(or eviction) policy is described here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/CacheParameterGroups.Redis.html

- maxmemory-policy
- maxmemory-samples

are what you're looking for.